# How to cancel a threaded task according to app condition

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I'm quite new in Task and maybe my question will be stupid or so, but I really need a help.

I would like to cancel task according to app condition.

Well, here we go:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    // Request cancellation from the UI thread.
    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'x')
    {
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(token), token);
    }
```

and here our DoSomeWork method:

```
    static void DoSomeWork(CancellationToken ct)
    {
    // Was cancellation already requested?
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("We were cancelled before we got started.");
     Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork() - Not Executed");
     return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork() - Executed");
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So, I expect that when I call
        tokenSource.Cancel();

this condition will be true:

```
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("We were cancelled before we got started.");
     Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork() - Not Executed");
     return;
    }
```

and I'll execute code inside if statement.

I definitively doing smth wrong and need exact steps of how to reach the goal described above.

Thank you in advance.
Julian

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: This sample from msdn cancelled for me  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested /* or all work is done*/)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomeWork");
}
Console.WriteLine("We were cancelled.");
```

Comment: The main idea is to split the main task into parts and check for ct.IsCancellationRequested after finishing each part.